# Blogdown serve_site() only serves the mobile version

Tags: r, knitr, blogdown

I am using the `Academic` theme with Blogdown. When I use the `blogdown:::serve_site()` function, it seems to only serve the mobile version of my site (large font, single column, mobile-first). I tried refreshing the browser after hitting "Show in new window" in RStudio, but it still keeps the mobile version. Sometimes, if I maximize the viewer pane in RStudio I can get a sort of hybrid version, where the site has columns but still some mobile features (large text). Is there a way to default to a web browser in `blogdown:::serve_site()`? Is this an issue with the site itself?

Comment: I actually use blogdown outside Rstudio but I have just run  my website in Rstudio and I have the same behaviour (I guess the RStudio viewer is considered as a xs device, this may be a setting that could be adjusted). I however am able to locally run my web browser (Firefox or Google Chrome) at the following adress http://127.0.0.1:4321/

Comment: For the record I use `Rscript -e "blogdown::serve_site()"` in a terminal and then I work with a web browser and I have the hugo message that gives me this adress.

Comment: Thank you @KevinCazelles. This allowed me to serve the site and discover that it definitely wasn't an RStudio issue, but a responsiveness problem with my version of Chrome.